# Blank space right side screen on small device or window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've a problem on my site, there is some blank space which appear when I resize the window under width:450px, and the space grow the smaller is the window. It's really a problem on some mobile. However I need to scroll to the right to see the space on firefox or chrome, on pc. The worst is, there is no space with the native browser of my phone... (android).

The website: start-track.fr

It's in French but we all speak the same language, HTML and CSS. :)

The code is quiet big so I will edit it if it really helps.

EDIT:
Screenshot:
[image: blank space on right side]

Comment: You have some element on a page with the width set wider than 450px. Try `overflow: hidden;` to see if it is true.

Comment: can you post a screen shot and the browser details here?

Comment: Please do not edit the word "solved" into the title. Instead, accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width in your media stylesheet:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 550px)
#copy {
    height: 12%;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 178px;
    left: calc(50% - 75px);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, could you explain how you found the problem please? I've look for it many hours...

Comment: Sure. I first enabled the toggle device mode in chrome dev tools. Then I went about deleting each parent node, checking each time if the problem persisted. When I understood that the problem was in the footer, I used the same method to narrow it down to that block of copyright text. Once that was done, inspect element and boom, the width had to be reduced. Glad I was of help. Please mark this answer as resolved by clicking on the check box beside the answer. Cheers.

Comment: I found the trick also but thanks. I thought that the dev tool would be enough. ^^

Answer (score 0):

1)In responsive site it's not recommend to use width with pixel,use percentage instead.

2)Active the tools developer(F12), and try to look which element is wide and because of him the browser active the overflow-x scroll.

3)After you find the problematic element, reduce his width.

If you have a problem let me know